# I can recover the key [ID] after a log in firebase - ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

> Hi, does anyone know how to retrieve a registry key in firebase after
>   adding it?

**I need to know if I can do this is my registration code.**

```
@Injectable()
    export class UsuarioProvider {

      usuariosItem = {} as UsuarioItem;
      usuarioItemRef$: AngularFireList<UsuarioItem[]>;
      constructor(public http: Http,
        private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.usuarioItemRef$ = this.database.list('usuario-list');
      }

      registrar_firebase(usuariosItem: any) {
        //console.log(usuariosItem);
        this.usuarioItemRef$.push({
          itemNombre: this.usuariosItem.itemNombre,
          itemEmail: this.usuariosItem.itemEmail,
          itemTelefono: Number(this.usuariosItem.itemTelefono)
        });
      }
```

Comment: what do you mean by registry key? The id of the pushed item?

Comment: Yes, that exactly @linasmnew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

**i.e.** using `snap.key`

```
 registrar_firebase(usuariosItem: any) {
       this.usuarioItemRef$.push({
          itemNombre: this.usuariosItem.itemNombre,
          itemEmail: this.usuariosItem.itemEmail,
          itemTelefono: Number(this.usuariosItem.itemTelefono)
        }).then((snap) => {
           const key = snap.key 
         });
      }
```

You can read about [**it here**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key).

Comment: Sorry @Samapth, how can i authenticate by phone number of firebase with ionic, some tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you first have to make an empty push to get back a key and then use that key with update to add your data under that key

You can do that as follows:

```
var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref(your_ref).push().key;

firebase.database().ref(your_ref+newPostKey).update({your_update_object});
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with the framework that you're using